# Why Is While Loop Not Working?

Tags: java, exception, while-loop, mouselistener

I have the following nested class inside a class that implements MouseListener:

```
public void plusOne()
    {       
    int reference = 0;
    int status = 0;
    System.out.println("BEGIN");
    System.out.println(dateArray[reference].selected);

    while (dateArray[reference].selected = false)
        {
        reference++;
        System.out.println("SUCCESS");
        }

        while (dateArray[reference].selected = true)
        {
        reference++;
        }   

        while (true)
        {
            if (dateArray[reference].status == 2)
            {
            dateArray[reference].status =1;
            status =2;
            break;
            }
            if (dateArray[reference].status == 3)
            {
            dateArray[reference].status =0;
            status = 3;
            break;

        }
        dateArray[reference].selected = true;
        reference++;    
        dateArray[reference].status = status;
        }


    }
```

System.out.prinln("BEGIN") is executed.
System.out.prinln(dateArray[reference].selected) is also executed. It should display the value "false" but it ALSO displays an error message of type

"Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" false

The next while loop is not executed.
Help Please!

Comment: First things first: the while loop has no business within a MouseListener. You're using linear console UI type code within an event-driven interface, and that is very wrong.

Comment: Next of all, if you're seeing an exception stacktrace and asking a question about it, you should post the **complete** stacktrace message, not a small part of it, and look through the stacktrace, find out which lines in your code it refers to, and indicate these lines for us.

Comment: @NiloOrlandi I think you should be using `==` instead of `=` in the while loops.

Comment: You shouldn't even have `==`. If you have `while (foo == true)` better to use the more succinct `while (foo)`.  But again, I posit that no while loop should be present. A while loop is used when you know that the code flow should stay completely within the loop until the condition is true, and this flies against event driven programming principles since with event-driven programs, the program flow is controlled by the user, and is captured by listening for events, not by constraining flow into while loops. Again, they will break your program, and so you need to get rid of them.

Comment: @Nilo-Orlandi Agree with HovercraftFullOfEels comment and upvoting it. That is even better.

Comment: So to look at your question in another way, what you likely are asking is an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) where you ask "how do I fix this code problem" when the best solution is to use a different approach entirely. Consider telling us the overall problem that you're trying to solve as well as the structure of the rest of the program rather than how you're currently trying to solve it.

Comment: I included the while loop INSIDE  a nested class which is SPECIFIC for the listener class. The single = was a typo, still not getting through to the while loop.

Comment: Please improve your question so that we know more about what behaviors you're trying to cause. This will give us a better chance to help you in depth.

Answer (score 0):

you wrote wrong syntax in java, trace your code and try like example code below

```
  while (dateArray[reference].selected == false){

  while (dateArray[reference].selected == true){
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that you're trying to force linear command line program type code into a single threaded event-driven programming environment, and this will likely completely freeze your GUI. For example this:

```
public void plusOne() {       
    int reference = 0;
    int status = 0;
    System.out.println("BEGIN");
    System.out.println(dateArray[reference].selected);

    while (!dateArray[reference].selected) {
        reference++;
        System.out.println("SUCCESS");
    }
    // ... here
```

Is fine in a simple console program since program code flow is dictated solely by you the programmer, but note that you'd likely have code within the while loop for user to enter code, and the program would wait patiently for the user to do this, then the loop would check the condition and decide whether to re-ask the user for input or proceed beyond the loop.

But this won't work in a single threaded Swing program since that while loop will block the Swing event dispatch thread and would then completely freeze the GUI. The solution is to get rid of the while loop and instead use if blocks and instance fields and vary your method's response depending on the state of the fields. The details of how you would implement this would depend on the details of your program and code, something we don't really know yet, but that you should tell and show us.

Answer (score -1):

The = should be ==

```
public void plusOne()
{       
int reference = 0;
int status = 0;
System.out.println("BEGIN");
System.out.println(dateArray[reference].selected);

while (!dateArray[reference].selected) //-----------
    {
    reference++;
    System.out.println("SUCCESS");
    }

    while (dateArray[reference].selected)  //-------------
    {
    reference++;
    }   

    while (true)
    {
        if (dateArray[reference].status == 2)
        {
        dateArray[reference].status =1;
        status =2;
        break;
        }
        if (dateArray[reference].status == 3)
        {
        dateArray[reference].status =0;
        status = 3;
        break;

    }
    dateArray[reference].selected = true;
    reference++;    
    dateArray[reference].status = status;
    }


}
```

Comment: Yes I know its superfluous but its not incorrect.  I was pointing out the = vs ==

Comment: Down-vote removed, but still the OP's *real* issue remains -- that the code he posted was in error, and in fact the single `=` did not represent the actual state of things, and that despite trying to fix it, the GUI will not progress beyond the first while loop. I stand by my suggestion that his main problem is to use while loops on the GUI's event thread. Unfortunately his question remains woefully incomplete, preventing us from giving him a concrete solution.